# Resize Chrome's window while using Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, selenium, rspec, capybara

I use Capybara (with selenium) and Chrome, and RSpec. But i would like to change width of browser in some tests. What is the solution in this case?

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

# Using chrome as browser to test in capybara.
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

# RSpec config.
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller    
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Clean test database.
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is [resize_to](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Window.html#resize_to-instance_method) function in Selenium Webdriver that you can use:

```
page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1024, 768)
```

[Window](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Window.html) has some other methods that may be useful.

Answer (score 6):

I've found that the `Driver#browser` call is now deprecated (Capybara 2.5.0).

You can use the [`Driver#resize_window_to`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Driver/Base#resize_window_to-instance_method) call to resize the window:

`page.driver.resize_window_to(page.driver.current_window_handle, 1_200, 800)`

You can also use [`Session#current_window`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Session#current_window-instance_method) then [`Window#resize_to`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Window#resize_to-instance_method):

`page.current_window.resize_to(1_200, 800)`

Look at the docs for more info:

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but someone may need this. You can initiate chromedriver by giving windows size so that you don't need to size it after loading the page:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome_sizes do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new 

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    :browser => :chrome,
    :profile => profile,
    :args => ["--window-size=1240,1400"]
  )
end
```

Comment: Here is the [link to a pre-definition code of *:selenium_chrome_headless*](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara.rb#L530-L536) for the sake of completeness. And [a tidbit](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot/issues/211#issuecomment-321857907) for those using it with [capybara-screenshot](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
it "testname", :js => true do
  set_selenium_window_size(1280, 800) if Capybara.current_driver == :selenium 
  # Resize window. NB: cannot be moved to before :all block, because there Capybara.current_driver will be :webkit. It changes to :selenium inside :js => true blocks.
  # ... the rest of your test ...
end

def set_selenium_window_size(width, height)
  window = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.window
  window.resize_to(width, height)
end
```

Thanks to Sidane for his gist https://gist.github.com/Sidane/2204218

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone still needs help with this issue:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: ['--window-size=1920,1080'])) end
```